# AFNetworking 3.0 Error: “Request failed: internal server error (500)”

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking-3

I am using Afnetwork 3. I am a new one for IOS development. I want to connect some API using POST method.

```
+(void)postExecuteWithParams:(NSString *)first  secondParm:(NSDictionary *)inParams onCompletion:(JSONResponseBlock)completionBlock {

NSString *baseURL = @"xyz";

AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:baseURL]];
manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

[manager POST:first parameters:inParams progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject)
 {

     NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
     completionBlock(responseObject);


     //here is place for code executed in success case

 } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {


     NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
 }];

}
```

When I use this code I am getting the error like this

Error: Request failed: internal server error (500)

can i know what is the reason for this error and how can i modify it?

Comment: internal server error (500) : Clearly states something went wrong at server. So your backend code is failing. Nothing much u can do from client end. Ask ur backend team to log the details and check whats going wrong

Comment: it is the backend error

Comment: Agree to @SandeepBhandari and also first check your service in Postman once it run on it call from your call, here is the link https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en

Comment: its working in postman but its not working in my code

Comment: @CharishmaVasamsetti then plz check with your headers,parmas,urls.

Comment: in my parameters 1 image file is existing, is there any issue with that

Comment: i have checked my code through breakpoints, and im not getting the response

Comment: Run your api in postman to see if any error occurred in it. If in postman it works fine than issue will be in your code.

Comment: in my code there is no error because i have tested different api's in the same code but for one particular api its not working

Answer (score 2):

It clearly says there was some error from server. It can also happen if you didn't correctly send the parameters. So check if you are sending all the required parameters, its spelling & the case. Also check if you missed any headers

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
  manager.securityPolicy.allowInvalidCertificates = YES;
  manager.securityPolicy.validatesDomainName = NO;
```

May be your server has not been published. So, with this you will not able to recieve internal server error.